# Javascript change size of div if blank or not

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want a div always have height `59%` when it has content and disappear when blank.

More explain in this photo:
[image: Example picture]

I use javascript to do, and try many ways but nothing happen. 
Here is my code:

```
<%--Html--%>

    <div id="main">
            <div id="content1">
             </div>
            <div id="down"> 
            </div>
        </div>

<%--CSS: in css file--%>
    #main
    {width:84%;height:78%;position:absolute;left:8%; top:14%; }
    #content1
    {width: 100%;height: 59%;overflow: auto;}
    #down
    {margin-top:0.5%;width: 100%;height: 40%;}

<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($("#content1").length < 1) {
                    $("#content1").height = 0%;
                    $("#down").height = 100%;
                    }
    else {   
    $("#content1").height = 59%;
        $("#down").height =40%;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few issues i notice... first your javascript should be called after the document has completed loading - to do this you want to place it within a

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

second i would use jquery to make assignments like with the .css({...}) function.

also it is definately worth mentioning that the conditional statement

```
if ($("#content1").length < 1)
```

is checking the number of elements that '#content1' contains, if you wanted to check for length of the string of html within that element you would use .html().

putting everything together, this is what the end result should look like

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         if ($("#content1").length < 1) {
              $("#content1").css('height', '0%');
              $("#down").css('height', '100%');
         }
         else {   
              $("#content1").css('height', '59%');
              $("#down").css('height', '40%');
         }
    });
```

using the css function of jquery this way will override the existing styles with the ones set.  now this script will only get called once after the DOM is initially loaded for the first time - so as long as the content on your page isn't changing everything should function properly

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that CSS height percentages is calculate relative to the height of the parent element.
If the parent element (and ALL parents) has no **explicit** height declared there is nothing to calculate and height in percentage does't work.